# Jmeter load test SAML Request

Tags: jmeter, saml

I am trying to load test a web application that uses SAML for SSO, using JMeter. Our server sends a SAML request to another server. In JMeter, how do I create these requests on the fly and parameterize this for many users?

Thanks in advance. If you know the solution, please let me know as soon as possible.

In view results tree, I see the following request:

```
/app/login
under this there are three requests
   https://xyz.org/app/start/login
   https://abc.com/saml/SamlSsoService?SAMLRequest=eJxlj8FuwjAQRM%2F5i8j3xAlItLIIiLaqikQrBKGH3hxnSQzJ2vU6UT%2B%2FFrQSao87uzP7Zr786rt4%0D%0ABEfaYMHyNGMxoDK1xqZgh%2FI5uWfLxZxk31mxGnyLO%2FgcgHwcBSOSuGwKNjgURpImgbIHEl6J%2Fep1%0D%0AIyZpJqwz3ijTsWj9VDAwra2atmrPnamk7JU5nQzKxlZHiVA3qM7HDk6KxdH7L1ZICWaiAdZIXqIP%0D%0AUpZnST5JsmmZz8RkJrK7DxZtf149aLw2%2BMOV3nJV1yMSL2W5TXZQawfKX0JGXYN7C46CoVVpSOyg%0D%0AgcpIV4ehZ9GKCJwPcI8GaejB7cGNWsFhtylY670lwXkN4%2FSf3biGkx9qQM%2BltTy00Ua1QZPOcyLD%0D%0AA4hnfPENC8GO7w%3D%3D%0D%0A&RelayState=abc%3Astart&appId=250
   https://def.com/account/login.jsp?destinationpage=start&applicationId=2
```

The second URL is the redirect URL. I want to capture what the system sends and tell JMeter to send it.

```
 SAMLRequest=eJxlj8FuwjAQRM%2F5i8j3xAlItLIIiLaqikQrBKGH3hxnSQzJ2vU6UT%2B%2FFrQSao87uzP7Zr786rt4%0D%0ABEfaYMHyNGMxoDK1xqZgh%2FI5uWfLxZxk31mxGnyLO%2FgcgHwcBSOSuGwKNjgURpImgbIHEl6J%2Fep1%0D%0AIyZpJqwz3ijTsWj9VDAwra2atmrPnamk7JU5nQzKxlZHiVA3qM7HDk6KxdH7L1ZICWaiAdZIXqIP%0D%0AUpZnST5JsmmZz8RkJrK7DxZtf149aLw2%2BMOV3nJV1yMSL2W5TXZQawfKX0JGXYN7C46CoVVpSOyg%0D%0AgcpIV4ehZ9GKCJwPcI8GaejB7cGNWsFhtylY670lwXkN4%2FSf3biGkx9qQM%2BltTy00Ua1QZPOcyLD%0D%0AA4hnfPENC8GO7w%3D%3D%0D%0A&RelayState=abc%3Astart&appId=250
```

Can you tell me the regular expression to use inorder to capture this value? Also, if there are three different URLs, how does jmeter know which one to capture?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATED

It looks like /start/login might be generating the token that gets passed to /saml/SamlSsoService.

I would try the structure below.  Note, you  need to have an HTTP request for each page. You  may need to add these manually.

```
ThreadGroup
- CSV Data Set Config 
- POST /app/start/login
- - Post Processor: Regular Expression
- POST /saml/SamlSsoService?{samlToken}
- POST /account/login.jsp
```

The CSV Data Set config points to CSV file with each user/password.  This allows for multiple users.

The SAML Token Request has the username/password as variables whose values are determined by the CSV file.

The Regular Expression extracts the valid SAML token and stores it to a variable.  The regex should be applied to the URL and would be something like this:

```
SAMLRequest=(.+?)
```

The SamlSsoService and login.jsp Requests have "SAML TOKEN" as a variable, allowing it to pass a unique SAML token to the server.

Resources:

- http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterFAQ
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor
- NEW! http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: I did some more checking and looks like when the user clicks on sign in button, it creates a redirect url with the saml request attached as url?saml=encrypted_saml_request_string. I need a way to capture this url before it is redirected, so that I can parameterize it. Any idea how I can intercept the redirect.

Comment: What does your script look like when you record logging in?

If the structure is:
 - GET login page
 - POST request for SAML Token
 - POST redirected URL

Then add a post processor to the SAML request to extract the token.

Comment: I added more info to the question.

Comment: @user373201, can you share test scripts, of course without csv files, I have same scenario. Thanks. Verma.praveen@gmail.com